# angular $injector:unpr Error

Tags: angularjs, code-injection

Im trying to use Resource in my app and I get the following error:

> $injector:unpr
>   "errors.angularjs.org/1.3.15/$injector/unpr?p0=mkResourceProvider%20%3C-%20mkResource%20%3C-%20mkController".

Here is my Code

app

```
var logApp = angular.module('mkApp', ['ngResource','ngRoute']);
```

Controller

```
angular.module('mkApp').controller('mkController', function ($scope, mkResource) {

$scope.ddl = [];

mkResource.LookUp(function (data) {
    $scope.ddl = data;
    console.log($scope.ddl);

});});
```

Resource

```
angular.module('mkApp').factory('mkResource', function ($resource, $http) {

var lookup = $resource('api/HowOftens');

function LookUp() {
    return lookup.query();
}

return {
    LookUp: LookUp
}});
```

HTML

```
<head>
<script src="../Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="../Scripts/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>

<title></title>
```

```
<div ng-app="mkApp">
    <div ng-controller="mkController">
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td> F Name</td>
                <td> L Name</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input type="text" /></td>
                <td><input type="text" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <slect></slect>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>

    </div>
</div>


<script src="MkApp/MkApp.js"></script>
<script src="Controller/MkController.js"></script>

<script src="../Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>    
<script src="../Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

From all the reading ive been doing i understand its injection error. I don't understand what Im not injecting properly though. The final plan was to load ddls from data I will receive.

Comment: is your code minimized?

Comment: no its all I have, Im trying to rewrite connection from HTTP to resource. I just fixed the error as well. It was the positioning of my references. Thank you though.

Comment: Is `mkResource` in the separate file?

Answer (score 0):

You would need to be loading your angular-route and angular-resource (your libs) before you actually load up your angular app files.

Comment: <script src="../Scripts/angular-resource.min.js"></script>
    <script src="../Scripts/angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script src="MkApp/MkApp.js"></script>
    <script src="Controller/MkController.js"></script> this didn't solve the issues same error occurs.